# Can Jenkins schedule builds using different time zones?

Tags: jenkins

In some versions of crontab you can set the time zone for when the job should run like:

```
TZ=GMT
30 11 * * *
```

This would run at 11:30am GMT every day, even if the server was in some other time zone.

Even though Jenkins scheduling is based on cron, it doesn't seem to have this specific syntax.  Is there some other way to do this in Jenkins?

Thanks

Comment: Here's the ticket to track this missing feature: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-9283

Answer (score 33, accepted):

As Michael mentioned in his answer, this functionality was added. Here's an example:

```
TZ=Europe/Kiev
0 1 * * 5
```

That would run at 1:00 AM Ukraine time, once a week on Friday.

To get the names of time zones to use, you can use the column marked "TZ database name" in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones

Comment: What version of Jenkins is this available? We are using 2.164 version and it can't identify TZ in the jenkins job scheduler.

Comment: I use Jenkins ver. 2.164.3. Setting time zone using TZ seems to work.

Answer (score 5):

Looks like they added this in 2.60.2.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to do this in Jenkins. You could trigger the builds by calling a URL from cron though.

Edit: This has since been added; see the other answers.

Comment: This is incorrect. See @twasbrillig response